# combine different cells to same row

Tags: excel, vba

I want each record on the same row:

```
Row 1 Column 1: Parcel Number,  Row 1 Column 2: Owner Name, Row 1 Column 3: Address
```

SAMPLE :

Parcel Record   21033540290000
Owner   Doe, John M, SR. & Jane H; TRS
Address 2116 W Wall St
Parcel Record   21033540450000
Owner   Brown, MARSHA & GREEN, MARIE; JT
Address 2131 W Harvard Ave
Parcel Record   21033230450000
Owner   Smith, MICHELLE K
Address 4281 S Yale Ave

I would like the format to be on the same row with 3 columns:

```
21033540290000  Doe, John M, SR. & Jane H; TRS          2116 W Wall St
21033540450000  Brown, MARSHA & GREEN, MARIE; JT        2131 W Harvard Ave
21033230450000  Smith, MICHELLE K                       4281 S Yale Ave
```

Then delete the Owner and Address rows after the data is copied to the same row as the Parcel number.

Have recorded  a macro, but have problem looping & referencing cells and rows.
Sub FormatRows()
'
' FormatRows Macro
' Formats to same row
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f

```
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B5").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Rows("4:4").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B4").Select
```

End Sub

' How can I get this to loop thru a couple thousand rows?

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you tried?  Is the issue with your loop, or with splitting the data into 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

This would require string processing

Step 1: Find the number part:

```
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strChar As String
strTemp = "Parcel Record 21033540290000 Owner Doe, John M, SR. & Jane H; TRS Address 2116 W Wall St "


flag = True
i = 1
On Error GoTo lblEnd:
While flag = True
    strChar = Strings.Mid(strTemp, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(strChar) Then
        'your code here
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

lblEnd:
Err.Clear
```

Step 2: Find "," and ":". Just change the if part of the previous code:

```
 If strChar = "," Then
     'your code here
 End If
```

and this:

```
 If strChar = ":" Then
     'your code here
 End If
```